# Definition od essential supremum for martingales with many measures

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathbb{P},\mathcal{F})$ and a filtration $\mathbb{F}=\left\{\mathcal{F}_t\mid\,t\in[0,T]\right\}$. Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a family of equivalent probability measures respect to $\mathbb{P}$, and $X$ a random variable. Is it possible to define
\begin{equation}
M_t=ess\sup_{\mathbb{Q}\in\mathcal{Q}}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t)
\end{equation}

and in this case is $M$  a submartingale $\mathbb{Q}\in\mathcal{Q}$? My question arises because the probabilty spaces where the conditional expectations are defined are not the same.

Comment: If $X$ is a martingale under any $\mathbb{Q}$, isn't $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}(X_T|\mathcal F_t) = X_t$?  Also, I don't think the probability spaces where the conditional expectations are defined are different: they are all defined on $\Omega$, just under different measures.

Comment: @user6247850 Yeah, you are right. I made a mistake, $X$ has not to be martingale. But in fact the the probability spaces change (they depend of the measure as you said). I have found some proofs of the existence of the essential supremum, but all them are based in a expectation (so in base of the measure).

Comment: Right, but ultimately $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}(X|\mathcal F_t)$ is just a random variable defined on $\Omega$ that satisfies some special properties relating to the measure $\mathbb{Q}$.  For the purposes of defining the essential supremum, they can be viewed just the same as any other collection of random variables.

Comment: But to define a supremum note that you need to define "how to compare two thinga", in the case "a.s.", you say $X\leq Y$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s., so to define the essential supremum in wich sense do you define it?

Comment: They are all equivalent, so $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. is also $\mathbb{Q}$-a.s. for all $\mathbb{Q}$.  Without that property, one would likely have to get into the specific version of $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[X|\mathcal F_t]$ one is talking about.

Comment: I get it! THank you very much for your answers. I found a definition in article about "incomplete markets for american options" but it is like you said. Thank you again <3.